# Wacom API, TextAlign on labels not working

Tags: c#, signaturepad, wacom

I'm using a [Wacom STU 530 signature tab](http://signature.wacom.eu/products/hardware/stu-530/) with the Signature SDK v3.20.4.

My problem is about text lining when creating labels.

```
/* We have this controller which was placed in a windows form
* It's that object that will mainly communicate with the Wacom tab
* It's already initialized, I'm showing this to just to show the type & name */
AxWizCtl WizCtl;

bool success = WizCtl.PadConnect()

if(isSuccess) {
    //Here I create a label with center align
    WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectText, id, x, y, text, TextOptions.TextAlignCenter);

    //Here I display the newly added elements on the signature pad
    WizCtl.Display();
}
```

The problem is that it will never be aligned, no matter which alignement from TextOptions I use. To be precise, it will be displayed and aligned to the left by default.

The documentation says that :

[image: Documentation for WizCtl.AddObject(ObjectType.ObjectText)]
[image: Documentation for TextOptions]

But it doesn't work and I don't know what to do.

Comment: The documentation comes with the SDK when you buy it, I don't know if there are officials ways to get the documentation without the SDK. https://developer-docs.wacom.com/display/DevDocs/Signature+SDK+-+Windows

Comment: Wow, very limiting platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the developer support at Wacom and got an answer.

> I am sorry, but text alignment and click events are not implemented in the API even though they are documented in the manual.

So as for today, it is not feasible with this API.